# How to serve files in Deno using serveFile?

Tags: typescript, localhost, deno

My script as follows, which compiles without errors, is suppose to serve index.html, however nothing is ever sent to the browser while the page is showing it's loading.

```
import { serve } from "https://deno.land/std@0.91.0/http/server.ts";
import { serveFile } from 'https://deno.land/std@0.91.0/http/file_server.ts';

const server = serve({ port: 8000 });
console.log("http://localhost:8000/");

for await (const req of server) {
  console.log(req.url);
  if(req.url === '/')
    await serveFile(req, 'index.html');
}
```

So why is serveFile not working in this instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `serveFile` only creates a [`Response`](https://deno.land/std@0.91.0/http/server.ts#L393) (status, headers, body) but doesn't send it.

You have to send it with a separate call to `req.respond()`:

```
import { serve } from "https://deno.land/std@0.91.0/http/server.ts";
import { serveFile } from 'https://deno.land/std@0.91.0/http/file_server.ts';

const server = serve({ port: 8000 });
console.log("http://localhost:8000/");

for await (const req of server) {
  console.log(req.url);
  if(req.url === '/') {
    const response = await serveFile(req, 'index.html');
    req.respond(response)
  }
}
```